# Why does Django's AuthenticationForm return weird str in error message

Tags: django

I've recently implemented the Django AuthenticationForm into my project and recognized that the error returns some weird str `__all__`

Returned error message in the frontend when using a wrong password:

[image]

My template

```
<div class="error-wrapper">
     <div class="errors">{{ form.errors }}</div>
</div>
```

So I took a look into the Django source code to check out the form which doesn't include `__all__` in the error message str:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    username/password logins.
    """
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password'}),
    )

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`.errors`** property [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) returns a *dictionary* of errors where the keys represent the field where the error occurred, and the value a list of errors. For errors that are not specific to one field, but to two or more fields, it will use `__all__`. These are thus non-field errors.

When you [*render a Django from in a template*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), you can use `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to render these, and `{{ form.some_field.errors }}` to render the errors dedicates to a certain field. You can also iterate over `form.non_field_errors` and `form.some_field.errors` to obtain the errors one-by-one, and render these in a different way.

You can thus render non-field errors with:

```
<div class="error-wrapper">
     <div class="errors">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Willem! So If I would have to change the error message itself, I would have to set up a subclass of the AuthentictionForm?

Comment: You can override the `error_messages` of a form to specify different messages. If Django fails to find the error message in a given class, it will look further up to the parent classes, until eventually it finds the correct error message. But the `__all__` is not related to the error message, this is the key that specifies that it is a error message that is not about a specific field.